# build a org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery from a javax.persistence.Query

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to use a single named query both for obtaining a set of results and to count the available amount of data. I have a named JPQL query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "query.all.absences.by.name", query = "SELECT a FROM Absence a WHERE a.name = :name")
```

When I obtain the Absences I'm invoking the query like this:

```
final Query q = em.createNamedQuery("query.all.absences.by.name");
q.setParameter("name","aRandomAbsenceName");
//maxResults and firstResult are coming as parameters, are computed in another method
q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
```

`q.getResultList()` gets me the correct result set. So far so good.

Now what I want to do is use the same named query to execute a count query.
I'm doing the following:

```
final Query q = em.createNamedQuery("query.all.absences.by.name");
q.setParameter("name","aRandomAbsenceName");
q.setHint(QueryHints.QUERY_TYPE, "org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery");
final ReportQuery test = JpaHelper.getReportQuery(q);
test.addCount();
test.setShouldReturnWithoutReportQueryResult(true);
```

This approach works fine if my named query does not have parameters. But with parameters, if I execute the ReportQuery defined above I have the following exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6094] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The parameter name [name] in the query's selection criteria does not match any parameter name defined in the query.
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=AbsenceCategory sql="SELECT COUNT(CATEGORY_KEY) FROM ABSENCE_CATEGORY WHERE (CATEGORY_KEY = ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.parameterNameMismatch(QueryException.java:1063)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ParameterExpression.getValue(ParameterExpression.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.translate(DatabaseCall.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2611)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllReportQueryRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2554)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:846)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1449)
```

How else can I possibly set the parameters to a ReportQuery?

I'm using EclipseLink 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you executing the ReportQuery?  You need to call Session.executeQuery(query, arguments) and pass a List of the arguments (order the same as query.getArguments().

You can probably also use the JpaEntityManager createQuery(DatabaseQuery) API to convert the ReportQuery back to a JPA Query, then you can just set the parameter the JPA way.

Comment: I'm executing it like this: 
`final Session session = ((JpaEntityManager) em.getDelegate()).getActiveSession();
final Vector reportRows = (Vector) session.executeQuery(test);
if (reportRows != null) {
 return ((BigDecimal) reportRows.get(0)).intValue();
}`

So I should explicitly set the query arguments to the ReportQuery, even though I'm setting the query parameters to the Query object?
`JpaHelper.getReportQuery(q);` does not convert the parameters of the given Query object into arguments for the ReportQuery?